# Problema con caracter `\n` al interpretar una fecha

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, datetime, date

Estimados, tengo un código para cambiar fechas de tipo `string` en un archivo texto a una lista de fechas del tipo `datetime`:

```
import datetime as dt
import workdays
Holidays = open("C:\holidays.txt").readlines()
print (Holidays)

dates_list = [dt.datetime.strptime(date, '"%Y-%m-%d"').date() for date in 
Holidays]
print(dates_list)
al leerlas con la funcion open("archivo.txt")
```

Tengo el siguiente error: **`ValueError: time data '2017-09-18\n' does not match format '"%Y-%m-%d"'`**. Al parecer al leer el texto se genera un caracter `\n` al final de la fecha y por eso no puedo transformar strings a fecha. El archivo de texto es UTF-8 sin BOM.

saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El `\n` es el caracter de fin de linea de cualquier archivo de texto. `readlines()` lo incluye en los ítems correspondientes a cada línea por lo que deberías quitarlo, usando por ejemplo `rstrip()`, así:

```
dates_list = [dt.datetime.strptime(date.rstrip(), '"%Y-%m-%d"').date() for date in 
Holidays]
```

Por otro lado te recuerdo que debes cerrar los archivos que has abierto, con `close()` o en su defecto y mejor aún usar un `contextmanager` que cierra automáticamente el archivo una vez que dejamos de necesitarlo:

```
with open("archivo.txt", mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    Holidays = f.readlines()
```

Comment: @ Patricio_Moracho edité la pregunta y puse una imagen con las opciones que me entrega notepad ++ de encoding. cual deberia escoger para no tener este problema?.

Comment: @Richie, si solo tienes fechas, es decir los caracteres que vas a tener son solo  números y eventualmente una barra (`/`) puede funcionar cualquier opción que no tenga BOM, prueba convertirlo a ANSI o en UTF-8 pero sin BOM.

Comment: Patricio edité la pregunta nuevamente. tu información se deshizo de los signos del comienzo. pero ahora cuando busca la fecha aparece un \n al final del string. sabes de que se puede tratar?

Comment: Si, el `\n` es el salto de línea, cuando lees un archivo de texto cada linea finaliza con ese caracter. Voy editar mi respuesta para hacerla mas acorde a tu nueva pregunta.

Comment: funcionó perfecto. muchísimas gracias!!!!